# How do you create self-referential nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

... or is it possible at all to create a node in Neo4j which has a relationship with itself (a simple loop-node)?

If so, what would be the corresponding Cypher query?

Answer (score 11):

The following query creates Peter who voted for himself.

```
MERGE (peter:User { name: "Peter" })
MERGE (peter)<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(peter)
RETURN peter
```